# delete tokens not detecting by eclipse what might be the solution?

Tags: java, spring, eclipse

[image]

Eclipse doesn't detecting the errors

Answer (score 1):

Your source file is not treated as `java source`
Please config you java source path in the `Project Properties` tab.

The source with an icon looks like this one:

[image]

Comment: As it is a maven module the java icon appears to be like that in spring boot.Any changes to in pom.xml will reflect the java source path